# Designing ElasticSearch Migration from 6.8 to 7.16 along with App Deployment

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, deployment, data-migration, resthighlevelclient

I have a Spring Boot application that uses ElasticSearch 6.8 and I would like to migrate it to Elasticsearch 7.16 with least downtime. I can do [rolling update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/rolling-upgrades.html) but the problem with migration is that when I migrate my ES cluster from version 6 to 7, some features in my application fails because of breaking changes (for example [total hit response change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/breaking-changes-7.0.html#hits-total-now-object-search-response))

I also upgraded my ElasticSearch client to version 7 in a separate branch and I can deploy it as well but that client doesn't work with ES version 6. So I cannot first release the application and then do the ES migration. I thought about doing application deployment and ES migration at the same time with a few hours downtime but in case something goes wrong rollback may take too much time (We have >10TB data in PROD).

I still couldn't find a good solution to this problem. I'm thinking to migrate only ES data nodes to 7.16 version and keep master nodes in 6.8. Then do application deployment and migrate ElasticSearch master nodes together with a small downtime. Has anyone tried doing this? Would running data and master nodes of my ElasticSearch cluster in different versions (6.8 and 7.16) cause problem?

Any help / suggestion is much appreciated

Comment: The breaking change you mention can be alleviated by using the query string parameter `rest_total_hits_as_int=true` in order to keep getting total hit count as in version 6 (mentioned in the same link you shared). Running master and data nodes with different versions is not supported and I would not venture into it. if you have a staging environment where you can test this upgrade procedure it's better. If you list all breaking changes you're suffering from, it's easier to assist you.

Comment: The problem I mentioned about total hits about response format. On ES7 hits.total is now an object in the search response, previously it was a numeric field. And ES6 client expects to find it at hits.total path. hits.total is the only issue I found so far but I haven't done a detailed test yet. I would like to avoid spending much on that if I can find a safer solution. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Sorry I misread your comment. Indeed the total.hits problem is resolved with rest_total_hits_as_int=true, thanks again

Comment: Cool, so if you add that small bit to your 6.8 client code, you should be able to upgrade your cluster to 7.16, since 6.8 clients are compatible with 7.16 clusters. When your ES server is upgraded, you can upgrade your application code to use the 7.16 client and you'll be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [breaking change you mention](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/breaking-changes-7.0.html#hits-total-now-object-search-response) can be alleviated by using the query string parameter `rest_total_hits_as_int=true` in your client code in order to keep getting total hit count as in version 6 (mentioned in the same link you shared).

Running master and data nodes with different versions is not supported and I would not venture into it. If you have a staging environment where you can test this upgrade procedure it's better.

Since 6.8 clients are compatible with 7.16 clusters, you can add that small bit to your 6.8 client code, then you should be able to upgrade your cluster to 7.16.

When your ES server is upgraded, you can upgrade your application code to use the 7.16 client and you'll be good.

As usual with upgrades, since you cannot revert them once started, you should test this on a test environment first.